# If ‘JANUARY’ is ‘JULY’ then August =?

Tags: pattern

I found this puzzle on another website and I wanted to share it here.
I will post the source link after a week to avoid spoilers.

Here are some rules:

```
'JANUARY' is 'JULY',
'SEPTEMBER' is 'SEPTEMBER',
'FEBRUARY' is 'AUGUST' 
and 'MARCH' is 'MAY' 
then 'AUGUST' is?
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

AUGUST IS

> JUNE

This is explained as

> The output answer is the month which has the same index in the year as the number of letters in the input.

Comment: If so, we're got 2 Augusts in the year: Both February and November have 8 letters.

Comment: I would use _index_ instead of _number_. To me it was not immediately clear which number a month has, _index_ indicates position.

Comment: This is more than likely the right answer. There is no evidence to support the "commutative operator" logic in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Vector The puzzle doesn't mention that it is forbidden to have duplicate months. This is perfectly valid and seems like the most logical solution.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - The implication is we're talking about the 12 months of the year, which have no duplicates - we're just shifting their positions.. That makes this answer incorrect. If not so, then the problem is very poorly stated.

Comment: @Vector It doesn't say you end up with 12 different months after applying the solution. But I agree, the problem is very poorly stated. Too much ambiguity.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid : **The implication is we're talking about the 12 months of the year** .

Comment: @Vector “the implication is...” means “based on **your** interpretation”. With the limited amount of information provided in this puzzle, you can’t definitively say this is a wrong solution because two different words both produce “August”. The way I see it, these are arbitrary words with a defined order. Might as well say “`ONE is THREE, TWO is THREE, THREE is FIVE...`”

Comment: @maxathousand - this **is** an incorrect solution - another answer has been accepted - and my question is one proof that it is incorrect. I am not sure why this is difficult - there are 12 unique months in a year and the question is clearly referring to **months of the year** in a particular order or abiding by a particular pattern, otherwise it really doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @Vector I also think OP selected the wrong answer. Agree to disagree, I suppose :) Also OP admitted to have selected the wrong answer, but [doesn’t know how to change it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57254/if-january-is-july-then-august/57277#comment176376_57277) :)

Comment: @maxathousand - OK - I disagree with the OP too. We can all agree to disagree... :)

Comment: @Vector OP posted the link to the site that also has the question and answer. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @lPlant - I see. That makes it a poorly designed puzzle.

Comment: ok, this is now solved.

Answer (score 9):

Answer is

> june

If,

> JANUARY (char 7) means 7th month - JULY
>  SEPTEMBER (char 9) means 9th month - SEPTEMBER
>  FEBRUARY (char 8) means month 8 - AUGUST
>  MARCH (char 5) means month 5 - MAY
>  AUGUST (char 6 ) means...

Comment: This is the same as [CodeNewbie's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57255/24755), posted almost a day earlier.

Comment: This is the same *answer* but has a more readable explanation, which makes it not completely redundant. Having said that, it only barely provides more information and probably shouldn't have been posted. @maxasela, you should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate. And where your answer is clearly derivative of an earlier one, acknowledging the original answer is generally recommended.

Comment: yes you got the right point.

Answer (score 8):

AUGUST is

> 'FEBRUARY' (as we should not forget past - that is refer line number 3)

Comment: So you also need to see rule number 2 Right?

Comment: This answer is more confusing than the puzzle.

Comment: I think @Mea is trying to say that = is a commutative operator, so if a = b, then b = a also.

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? Can anybody explain the logic behind it? So far the answer of maxasela seems most logic to me =/...

Comment: What evidence do you have to support the logic employed in this answer?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri never seen more upvotes on a comment than there are on the post itself before.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It seems to consider "x is y" as "x = y", and since "x = y" and "y = x" mean the same thing, that would be the answer. Of course, this isn't logical at all - something can _be_ something else without being equal to that other thing. ("The sun is a star, but not all starts are the sun", for example.)

Comment: guys You are going on the wrong track.

Comment: @user6433464 then why did you accept this answer if it’s “on the wrong track”?

Comment: @user6433464 you linked to the site where you got this question which provides an answer and this is blatantly not the answer. Why did you accept this?

Comment: from my side the answer given in provided link is correct And the logic is proper If you have doubt you can share your answer with correction @IPlant